# Named pipes in java on LAN and over internet

Tags: java, file, stream, named-pipes

I'm trying to read file in LAN network using java `FileInputStream`. Everything ok on same machine with localhost address. But on the other computer in LAN it can't see my file, I only get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Part of my code:

```
    File pipe = new File("\\\\127.0.0.1\\SharedFolder\\pipe");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pipe);
    int i=-1;
    while((i=fis.read())!=-1){
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }
```

So if i change address to LAN address where I created shared folder and if try to access it from another computer in the same LAN network it  won't work. SharedFolder is a windows shared folder with all permission for all users with pipe file in it.  Is there analogue in `java` like in `c#` `NamedPipesServerStream` and `NamedPipesClientStream`?

I don't want use windows pipes because I want my application work on both unix and windows, so I thought I could use just files. And I don't want to use sockets.

And the next question. Is it possible to do the same thing over internet network?

Comment: Why not use sockets? TCP is ideal for transferring files while still being relatively easy to set up

Comment: You can't use files for `\\server\share\dir\file` because that's not a file or "named pipe". Files must exist on the local filesystem. `\\server\..` files don't. They are like `http://server/somefile` but instead of http "windows share" / samba. You can use a samba library in java to access those but that will use sockets anyways.

Comment: You don't want to use named pipes but your question is entitled 'named pipes'. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @redFIVE, I already have realization with sockets, and just wanted to try pipes.

Comment: @zapl, so there is no way to access some file without sockets?

Comment: @EJP, I red that to make named pipe i should use 'mkfifo' which creates file - pipe, so I thought that pipe is just a file. So then I can use with it FileInpuStream or FileOutoutStream, am I right?

Comment: If there is a network cable or wifi-waves in between you and the hard drive that stores the file, there has to be sockets because they do communication via network interfaces. In unix everything is a file handle even sockets, which makes it a bit confusing but regular files and pipes don't work across networks.

Comment: Then what is the point of shared folder if a can't read a file?

Comment: It appears as if it was a file in your file manager / explorer but it's not a "real" file. File managers do nothing but load a list of files from somewhere, either over a SATA cable from a disk or over a network cable. So it kind of doesn't matter. But the connection over network is called socket, the one over SATA cable isn't. And you can read the file. There is just a difference in how you do that.

Comment: So, lets forget about pipes for a second. Is there way to access file remotely without sockets?

Comment: No. Unless you consider accessing a virtual local file that is emulated by a tool such as "smb mount" (or when you mount a shared folder in windows to a network drive with it's own letter) as access without sockets. In this case your software doesn't use sockets, the smb mount driver on the other hand translates all the things you do with the virtual file to socket actions for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block

Comment: Ok, i see. And so there is no analogue in java like in c# NamedPipesServerStream and NamedPipesClientStream?

Comment: C# uses the Win32 named pipes behind (at least this is the Microsoft implementation, not sure what Mono is doing), and those can communicate across computers in a Windows LAN (they are transported over SMB). UNIX pipes can't, they are only local. The closest thing I see in Java (besides using sockets, which would be in my opinion the natural solution to have a bidirectional communication channel) is RMI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), which allows calling methods on objects that are created on other machines...

Comment: I'm not sure. But looks like this is what can help me https://jcifs.samba.org/

Answer (score 0):

So I did not find any pipe related libs for java, but found one for files manipulation https://jcifs.samba.org/. So then I can emulate a primitive pipes. And it could be done on both windows and linux.

Comment: So you do want to use named pipes even though you don't. Clear as mud.

Comment: I did want to use named pipes, but not Windows's named pipes.